# Crop image with dynamic rectangle coordinate

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Image and I want crop it by using a rectangle, code below is the code I put a image and draw a rectangle at middle of the image:

**MainPage.Xaml:**

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="340" Height="480" Background="Blue">
        <Image x:Name="photo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ManipulationMode="All">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,340,480"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
```

I able to move the image. Code below is to transform the image, and the crop function is working. How do I bind the data and set the rectangle coordinate to dynamic instead of hard code coordinate? Thanks.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage: Page
{
        private CompositeTransform compositeTranslation;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            photo.ManipulationDelta += Composite_ManipulationDelta;
            compositeTranslation = new CompositeTransform();
            photo.RenderTransform = this.compositeTranslation;
        }

        void Composite_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // scale the image.
            compositeTranslation.CenterX = photo.ActualWidth / 2;
            compositeTranslation.CenterY = photo.ActualHeight / 2;
            compositeTranslation.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
            compositeTranslation.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
            compositeTranslation.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
            compositeTranslation.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        }

        private void btnCrop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var _rect = new RectangleGeometry();
            _rect.Rect = path.Data.Bounds;
            photo.Clip = _rect;
        }
}
```

Comment: So what should be the rectangle position? It should also move with rectangle? The relative position of rectangle and image should be fixed?

Comment: The rectangle is fixed at middle of the screen,only the image can move. And the rectangle crop size is always 340x480. Thanks

Comment: Rectangle should be in middle of the screen or image?

Comment: Rectangle should be in middle.

Comment: Rectangle would be in middle of screen and image can be panned. The content within rectangle will be clipped, am I right?

Comment: For now is Yes, because now is just for testing. The alignment of rectangle can left or right on final product. The most important is the content within rectangle will be clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using below code, rectangle would be in middle of screen and image can be panned. The content within rectangle will be clipped.

```xml
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar IsSticky="True" IsOpen="True">
        <Button Content="Crop" Click="btnCrop_Click" />
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image x:Name="photo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ManipulationMode="All" Source="http://www.wired.com/reviews/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Windows-8-1.jpg" />
    <Path x:Name="path" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3" />
</Grid>
```

```csharp
private CompositeTransform compositeTranslation;
RectangleGeometry rect = new RectangleGeometry();
public BlankPage4()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    rect.Rect = new Rect((Window.Current.Bounds.Width - 480) / 2, (Window.Current.Bounds.Height - 340) / 2, 480, 340);
    path.Data = rect;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    photo.ManipulationDelta += Composite_ManipulationDelta;
    compositeTranslation = new CompositeTransform();
    photo.RenderTransform = this.compositeTranslation;
}

private void btnCrop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GeneralTransform gt = photo.TransformToVisual(null);
    Point pt = gt.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
    var _rect = new RectangleGeometry();
    _rect.Rect = new Rect((rect.Bounds.X / compositeTranslation.ScaleX) - (pt.X / compositeTranslation.ScaleX), (rect.Bounds.Y / compositeTranslation.ScaleY) - (pt.Y / compositeTranslation.ScaleY), 480 / compositeTranslation.ScaleX, 340 / compositeTranslation.ScaleY);
    photo.Clip = _rect;
}

void Composite_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // scale the image.
    compositeTranslation.CenterX = photo.ActualWidth / 2;
    compositeTranslation.CenterY = photo.ActualHeight / 2;
    compositeTranslation.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
    compositeTranslation.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
    compositeTranslation.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    compositeTranslation.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

**Updated:** Code updated as told by Howard Hee
*solving the issue wherein zooming in/out will show only black screen*

Comment: But when I zoom out and click crop, the cropped image is out of rectangle. Can you solve it?

Comment: Finally I change the code to this to solve the problem. _rect.Rect = new Rect((rect.Bounds.X / compositeTranslation.ScaleX) - (pt.X / compositeTranslation.ScaleX), (rect.Bounds.Y / compositeTranslation.ScaleY) - (pt.Y / compositeTranslation.ScaleY), 480 / compositeTranslation.ScaleX, 340 / compositeTranslation.ScaleY)